# Android Play default ring-tone and vibration alert on receiving text Messages

Tags: android, ringtone, vibration

HI, 
I am working on a small android application. Application receive text messages from other phones. I want to Play default ring-tone and vibration alert onReceiving Messages event according to user current settings. i.e. If mobile phone isn't silent and vibration is off, then it plays ring-tone and if mobile phone is silent and vibration is on, it should vibrate onRecieve event.
Thank you

Comment: and whats the question? We won't make your homework for you. Also, why do you need to create an App for that, that's Android standard functionality.

Comment: I have an application that communicates with other application through text messages. I want to play ring-tone/vibration according to user current text message settings for alerting, When text message will receive on other end.

Comment: I still don't get why you need to do this on your own. This is Androids basic functionality. Or do you want a different Sound/Vibration depending on what is in the Text-Message?

Comment: I am writing my own Receive/send functionality.  I want to play ring-tones/sounds set by user in text messages settings,

Comment: Here is an example on how you can receive an SMS in your own App: [Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.html)
When you received the SMS, you can do whatever you want like playing a Sound or make the Device vibrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

junto,

One you set your notification, you just have to add flags to indicate you want the default sound to play as well as vibrate.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder,
            "My Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```